# Bootstrap 4 Checkbox is not aligning correctly

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a  form inside  which I have several input fields and one checkbox

- I am trying to align the input fields in one rows but its is not happening
- I am aligning checkbox next to input field
- I want to align in a way so that it should appear good on each device as I am using bootstrap
- I am using `class=form-control` but still not getting the perfect alignment

**Snippet**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container form-group">
  <form id="changePasswordForm">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="distributorName" id="commonHeader">Distributor
      Name:</label>
        <select id="distributorName" class="form-control test">

        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="userCode" id="commonHeader">User Code:</label> <input type="text" id="userCode" name="usercode" class="form-control commonClass" placeholder="user Code" readonly="readonly">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="userName" id="commonHeader">Name of the User:</label> <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" class="form-control commonClass" placeholder="User Name">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="loginId" id="commonHeader">login Id:</label> <input type="text" id="loginId" name="loginid" class="form-control commonClass" placeholder="Login Id">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="Pass" id="commonHeader">Password:</label> <input type="password" id="Pass" name="pass" class="form-control commonClass" placeholder="Password" required="required">
        <button type="button" class="eye-button" onclick="show('newPass')" id="display1">
      <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
     </button>

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="userRole" id="commonHeader">Role</label>
        <select id="userRole" class="form-control test">

        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="checkbox" id="commonHeader">Active
       </label> <input type="checkbox" id="active" class="form-control commonClass">

      </div>

    </div>
    <div>
      <hr>

      <button type="submit" id="save" class="commonButton">
      <i class="fa fa-save"></i>save
     </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to align all input fields in one row with the checkboxes next to it?

Answer (score 0):

You are giving it the input field a width of 100%, try changing the display property to block like below. (d-block)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container form-group">
  <form id="changePasswordForm">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="distributorName" id="commonHeader">Distributor Name:</label>
        <select id="distributorName" class="form-control test">
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="userCode" id="commonHeader">User Code:</label> 
        <input type="text" id="userCode" name="usercode" class="form-control commonClass" placeholder="user Code" readonly="readonly">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="userName" id="commonHeader">Name of the User:</label> 
        <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" class="form-control commonClass" placeholder="User Name">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="loginId" id="commonHeader">login Id:</label> 
        <input type="text" id="loginId" name="loginid" class="form-control commonClass" placeholder="Login Id">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="Pass" id="commonHeader">Password:</label> 
        <input type="password" id="Pass" name="pass" class="form-control commonClass" placeholder="Password" required="required">
        <button type="button" class="eye-button" onclick="show('newPass')" id="display1">
          <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="userRole" id="commonHeader">Role</label>
        <select id="userRole" class="form-control test">
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for="checkbox" id="commonHeader">
          Active
        </label> 
        <input type="checkbox" id="active" class="d-block">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <hr>
      <button type="submit" id="save" class="commonButton">
        <i class="fa fa-save"></i>save
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```